# Show Closed Captions on Video Load in JWPlayer 7

Tags: jwplayer, closed-captions

I am using JWPlayer 7 in my application and setup vtt file and i can see the 'CC' button and toggle closed captions. Is it possible that i can turn on closed captions on video load or via java-script? At the moment user has to click 'CC' button to turn them on/off.

Answer (score 0):

Use this while setting up the JWPlayer

```
tracks: [{
            file: "file.vtt",
            label: "English",
            kind: "captions",
            "default": true
            }],
```

the default = true will load subtitles automatically.